# Using V8 Isolate in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, v8

I have a program that uses a v8 isolate to execute javascript code.  I would like to spawn a separate thread and execute code in the isolate there too.  The thread does *not* need to run in parallel, I am only using the separate thread so I can cancel it from a signal handler on the main thread.

I am currently using pthreads to create the separate thread.  Like this:

```cpp
Isolate *isolate = Isolate::New(params);
int thread_id;
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, call, isolate);
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
```

Where `call` is the following very basic code to test locking the isolate.

```cpp
void *call(void* vargs) {   
    Isolate *isolate = (thread_args *) vargs;
    try {
        v8::Locker lock(isolate);
        isolate->Enter();
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
        v8::Isolate::Scope scope(isolate);
        /* use isolate exclusively in here */
        isolate->Exit();
    } catch catch (int err) {
        /* log error */
    }
}
```

The above yields the following stack trace:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../src/api/api.h, line 409
# Debug check failed: blocks_.empty().
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x16b612c88
==== C stack trace ===============================

            0x0000000115378eb0 v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 24
            0x0000000115354f3c v8::platform::(anonymous namespace)::PrintStackTrace() + 116
            0x0000000115362d1c V8_Fatal(char const*, int, char const*, ...) + 268
            0x0000000115362740 std::__1::enable_if<((!(std::is_function<std::__1::remove_pointer<char>::type>::value)) && (!(std::is_enum<char>::value))) && (has_output_operator<char, v8::base::CheckMessageStream>::value), std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>::type v8::base::PrintCheckOperand<char>(char) + 0
            0x00000001153f69e4 v8::internal::HandleScopeImplementer::Free() + 216
            0x000000011567c02c v8::internal::ThreadManager::FreeThreadResources() + 164
            0x000000011567c484 v8::Locker::~Locker() + 76
            0x0000000115340ca0 call(void*) + 144
            0x000000018f2e626c _pthread_start + 148
            0x000000018f2e108c thread_start + 8
```

It looks like the Locker destructor is trying to free resources that haven't been allocated properly.  Is there a data structure or method I need to call to ensure these resources a properly allocated when using threads and lockers?

Comment: `v8::Locker lock(targs->isolate);` -- The `v8::Locker` is local to the `try{ }` scope, thus will be immediately destroyed when the closing brace is hit.  Is this your intention?

Comment: Yup, I won't be using the isolate outside the `try` (updated the example to be a little clearer, thanks!)

Comment: You do realize that destructors are deterministic in C++.  They will be called on automatic variables once they leave the block scope.  I have never used `v8::Locker`, but it still follows the same rules as any other automatic type.  So if the destructor for `v8::Locker` is written with dependencies on other entities, then yes, you have to be much more careful in where you are using it.  Maybe just create one dynamically (using `new`, where you control when the destruction takes place (by issuing a `delete`).

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve]. My example works well.

Comment: Okay, I'm currently modifying code in https://github.com/plv8/plv8 , so maybe the exercise of creating the minimum example and then slowly adding code back will reveal the culprit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *The thread does **not** need to run in parallel*
   You do not need to lock with `v8::Locker lock(isolate);`
2. `Debug check failed: blocks_.empty().`
   You don't seem to enter the isolate `v8::Isolate::Scope scope(isolate);` after the lock.

```
void *call(void* vargs) {   
    Isolate *isolate = (thread_args *) vargs;
    try {
        v8::Locker lock(isolate);
        v8::Isolate::Scope scope(isolate);
        /* use isolate exclusively in here */
    } catch catch (int err) {
        /* log error */
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

---

Just tried. Can not reproduce. Works well.

```
void call(v8::Isolate *isolate) {
    v8::Locker lock(isolate);
    v8::Isolate::Scope scope(isolate);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    v8::V8::SetFlagsFromCommandLine(&argc, argv, true);
    auto *allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams params;
    params.array_buffer_allocator = allocator;

    auto *isolate = v8::Isolate::New(params);
    std::thread thread(call, isolate);
    thread.join();

    isolate->Dispose();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::DisposePlatform();
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and added the `v8::Isolate::Scope scope(isolate);`, (and updated the example code), but the fatal error and stack trace remain the same.

Comment: We need to know what is there `/* use isolate exclusively in here */`.

Comment: There is currently nothing in there, I'm just trying to test the creation/deletion of the lock.  The error manifests without using the isolate at all.

Comment: Ok. Will try it on my PC.

Comment: Try adding a `v8::HandleScope` too. See [test-lockers.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/test/cctest/test-lockers.cc;l=1?q=v8::HandleScope) for lots of examples of locked multi-threaded Isolate access.

Comment: Updated the code with the same result, but continuing to look at test-lockers.cc .  I wonder if I should be using subclassing `public v8::base::Thread` to do thread operations?

Comment: `isolate->Enter()` or `Isolate::Scope`, not both. (The latter is a convenience helper that does the former under the hood.) -- I don't think `v8::base::Thread` is needed, it's mostly a platform abstraction layer. That said, if it makes things easier, go for it.